service docker start doesn't work if systemd is enabled
If I have this in my /etc/wsl.conf file service docker start doesn't work:
[boot]
systemd=true

If I comment out the systemd=true bit service docker start works but not with that line in place.
wsl --version returns this:
WSL version: 2.2.4.0
Kernel version: 5.15.153.1-2
WSLg version: 1.0.61
MSRDC version: 1.2.5326
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.26091.1-240325-1447.ge-release
Windows version: 10.0.22631.4037

lsb_release -a returns this:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

docker --version returns this:
Docker version 25.0.3, build 4debf41

Here are the logs:
https://pastebin.com/KH1073uy
Any ideas?

Which installation method did you use?

Also service docker start shouldn't work (unless it is installed incorrectly?).  Do you mean sudo service docker start?  Or are you running as root?

@NotTheDr01ds - https://pastebin.com/GEHP3qTa is how I installed it. Those steps come from an earlier version of the link you posted. As for service docker start...  in /etc/wsl.conf, in the [boot] section, command=service docker start works just fine. But yes, unless you're doing something like that or you're running as root, then you'd need sudo.
